# How should I structure a config file to accept mutually exclusive parameters?

Tags: python, configuration, type-hinting, configparser

I'm writing a Python program that should accept input data from either a CSV file or a database. The structure of the data will be identical, it's just the method of getting the data. I'd like to put the configuration for getting that data into a config file (along with other options), and then ideally have that config nicely structured and type-hinted. So for example, I'd like to end up with something along the following lines:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol
import pandas as pd

class ReadableConfig(Protocol):
    def read(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        ...

@dataclass
class FileConfig:
    path: str

    def read(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        ...

@dataclass
class DBConfig:
    uri: str
    username: str
    password: str
    ...

    def read(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        ...

@dataclass
class AppConfig:
    input_source: ReadableConfig
```

My question: are there existing patterns or best practices for structuring the config file itself for a situation like this, where there are mutually-exclusive options? Whether it's using ConfigParser or json or anything else doesn't matter too much to me, although **I cannot use any 3rd party packages for this** because of work requirements (aside from pandas used above).

I suppose a simple solution is just to have either of the following:

```
# config file
input_path = some/file/path
```

```
# alternative
input_uri = some.uri
input_port = ####
```

and in the config parsing code, just do a bunch of if statements to check for different options being there, but that doesn't feel super elegant.

Are there any suggestions or known best ways to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the answers to your question will be rather subjective either way.

With all due respect, the `dataclasses` module is very weak IMHO compared to other projects out there that do similar things. I personally like [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) very much, but there are other options as well. One reason is the fact that dataclasses don't support basic type validation/coersion and don't support nesting out of the box. So your `AppConfig` may have a field that is itself typed as some dataclass, but a nested dictionary with the correct keys will not be properly parsed, when you initialize it.

There are workarounds, but you essentially have to write that logic yourself. Pydantic does this very well out of the box. Also, they have very neat built-in extensions for settings managament, including loading configuration from multiple different sources, which is exactly what you are doing here. But you said, you don't want external dependencies, so here we are...

One way to approach this is just try and coerce the `input_source` value you read into your `AppConfig` to the concrete `ReadableConfig` classes one at a time, until one of them works.

As a side note, I would make `ReadableConfig` an ABC rather than a protocol to enforce subclass implementation of the `read` method at *runtime* rather than just via type checks. Thus, `FileConfig` and `DBConfig` would inherit from it.

Here is a very simplistic implementation of a `from_dict` class method that tries to initialize an `AppConfig` instance with data from a dictionary:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Mapping
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import Any

...

@dataclass
class AppConfig:
    input_source: ReadableConfig

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data: dict[str, Any]) -> AppConfig:
        for f in fields(cls):
            if f.name != "input_source":
                continue
            value = data.get(f.name)
            if not isinstance(value, Mapping):
                raise TypeError(f"'{f.name}' must be a mapping")
            try:
                data[f.name] = FileConfig(**value)
            except TypeError:
                data[f.name] = DBConfig(**value)
        return cls(**data)
```

This could be easily extended to an arbitrary number of fields of `ReadableConfig` type. The downside would be that you need to specify in advance, which subclasses of `ReadableConfig` to try for parsing those fields.

Since your schemas for the different input source configurations do not overlap, this should work well enough. If the number of mutually exclusive configurations gets much bigger, I would begin to question the design altogether.

Here is a full working example :

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import json
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from collections.abc import Mapping
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any

import pandas as pd


class ReadableConfig(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def read(self) -> pd.DataFrame: ...


@dataclass
class FileConfig(ReadableConfig):
    path: str

    def read(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return NotImplemented


@dataclass
class DBConfig(ReadableConfig):
    uri: str
    username: str | None = None
    password: str | None = None

    def read(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return NotImplemented


@dataclass
class AppConfig:
    input_source: ReadableConfig
    foo: str
    bar: int = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data: dict[str, Any]) -> AppConfig:
        for f in fields(cls):
            if f.name != "input_source":
                continue
            value = data.get(f.name)
            if not isinstance(value, Mapping):
                raise TypeError(f"'{f.name}' must be a mapping")
            try:
                data[f.name] = FileConfig(**value)
            except TypeError:
                data[f.name] = DBConfig(**value)
        return cls(**data)

    @classmethod
    def load_json(cls, path: Path) -> AppConfig:
        with path.open("r") as file:
            return cls.from_dict(json.load(file))


def test() -> None:
    conf1 = {"foo": "abc", "input_source": {"path": "foo/bar"}}
    conf2 = {"foo": "xyz", "bar": 42, "input_source": {"uri": "spam:///eggs"}}
    app_conf1 = AppConfig.from_dict(conf1)
    app_conf2 = AppConfig.from_dict(conf2)
    print(app_conf1)
    print(app_conf2)
    try:
        AppConfig.from_dict({"foo": "abc", "input_source": {"x": "y"}})
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

The output:

```
AppConfig(input_source=FileConfig(path='foo/bar'), foo='abc', bar=0)
AppConfig(input_source=DBConfig(uri='spam:///eggs', username=None, password=None), foo='xyz', bar=42)
DBConfig.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

If it were up to me, I would still go for Pydantic settings and `YAML` configuration files, but that results in two explicitly added dependencies.

Comment: I was moreso asking about what you called the "schema" of the configuration file and not how to parse it, but your answer did give me a couple ideas and, though I wasn't asking for it, did convince me a bit that it might be worth the hassle of getting my work to allow a dependency for pydantic.